# add a counter column based on categories of other columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a counter column to my dataframe based on the combination of two categorical values. e.g:

```
dat <- data.frame(cat1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
              cat2 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "j", "j", "k", "l"), 
              Result = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3))
```

I have used this:

```
dat$Result <- ave(dat$cat1, dat$cat2, FUN=function(x) match(x,sort(unique(x))))
```

but I have errors. I have checked similar suggestions in other threads but the answers only apply to numeric columns. Could anybody please offer me a suggestion? Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
with(dat, as.numeric(ave(as.character(cat2), cat1,
             FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x)))))
```

If the `factor` levels are already in the same order for 'cat2', then coercing to `numeric` can also be done

```
with(dat, ave(as.numeric(cat2), cat1, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

#### Update

With the new dataset,

```
with(dat, as.numeric(ave(as.character(cat2), cat1, FUN = 
  function(x) inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values <- seq_along(values))))))
 #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun. This works partially but it is my fault because I did not include the best example. This should be clearer: dat <- data.frame(cat1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), cat2 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "j", "j", "k", "l", "k"), Result = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)) . Note that I have added a last registry. The result should recognize a part even as new when it comes up even it was identified before. Thank you.

Comment: I meant as a "pair even", sorry

Comment: @Mrrecio  Updated the post.  You can check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, Result := rleid(cat2), by = cat1]
dat
#   cat1 cat2 Result
#1:    a    x      1
#2:    a    x      1
#3:    a    x      1
#4:    a    y      2
#5:    a    y      2
#6:    b    j      1
#7:    b    j      1
#8:    b    k      2
#9:    b    l      3
```

Comment: Thank you Sotos. Unfortunately, I am dealing with POSIX information and complex numbers and them all seem not accepted by data.table. I transform them but I would prefer to find a method that keeps the original format to avoid succesive conversions. Moreover, the code did not worked for my case, it all is classified as number 1 in "Result"